# How does laravel validator pass value to the variables(like :min) in validation error messages?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I added a custom validation and it's working properly except the custom error message.

My custom validator:

```
public function getLength($value) {

    return (strlen($value) + mb_strlen($value, 'utf8'))/2;

}

public function validateLengthMin($attribute, $value, $parameters) {

    return $this->getLength($value) >= $parameters[0];

}
```

My custom error message:

```
'custom' => array(

    'username' => array(

          'length_min' => 'The :attribute must be at least :min characters.',

    )
)
```

The error message I got is: The username must be at least `:min` characters. What I wish to get is the minimum length I put in the validation (i.e. `lengthMin:6`, and I get `6` instead of `:min`) .

Another question is I wish to make the error message works for all inputs rather than only `username`. Therefore I tried this:

```
'custom' => array(

     "length_min" => "The :attribute must be at least :min characters.",

)
```

but it didn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: can you show us how do you run your validation code ?

Comment: Hi @SamyMassoud, `$validator = Validator::make(['username' => Input::get('username')], ['username' => 'lengthMin:6']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in documentation [here](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#custom-error-messages)

> When creating a custom validation rule, you may sometimes need to
>   define custom place-holder replacements for error messages. You may do
>   so by creating a custom Validator as described above, and adding a
>   replaceXXX function to the validator.

Then you have to create replacer function inside your custom validator class like this

```
protected function replaceLengthMin($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters)
{
    return str_replace(':min', $parameters[0], $message);
}
```